# Docker: How to include big folder to container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I have a Docker Compose setup with three different `services`. But I have a problem regarding file size in Docker.

In order to serve images to our users, our server (written in Java/Spring) looks to a local directory called `Images`, also this directory is used to save new images, this directory is almost `50 GB` in size and I can't include it inside `Docker Container` because of size limitations.

I created an `Images` folder inside *the container* then tried to `symlink` between the `Images` in *the host* machine. But it also failed.

My question is, how can I give access to this folder inside the container?

Comment: You can set the folder as a volume to the container. It won't copy it inside the container, but it'll work like a symlink. The changes made to the files inside that volume will work both way.

Comment: You should mount your `Images` folder in docker container to host container. Best solution is to serve all the static contents like images in your case from a CDN or other services like S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a size limit to the Docker container known as base device size. The default value is 10GB.

You can increase this value by setting up `storage-opt` option to the docker run command. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container

Or, if you are running it in `docker-compose` see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#storage_opt